# Is a probable prime known larger than the largest known prime?

Tags: number-theory, soft-question, prime-numbers, twin-primes

According to Wikipedia, the largest known prime is $2^{57,885,161}-1$ with $17,425,170$ digits.

Because a probable prime is usually easier to find than a proven prime
(although for the Mersenne-primes, there is an algorithm to prove primilaty
as fast as a probable prime test), I wonder if there is a larger known probable
prime.

The same for twin primes, the largest known pair is $3,756,801,695,685\times 2^{666,669}\pm1$ with $200,700$ digits. Is there known a larger pair for which both entries are probable primes ?

Comment: Probably known but not published. Note that we are talking about ranges where being satisfied with a highly probable prime is not useful, and someone publishing that they found a *probable* prime is something I find unlikely. Then again, there may be a community out there where probable primes, being candidates for primeness-provers, are collected. And as you say, for "structured" primes such as Mersenne, a definite proof can be as fast as a probale test.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The largest collection of (large) probable primes that I have seen is that of Henri & Renaud Lifchitz:

http://www.primenumbers.net/prptop/prptop.php

The largest PRP there is $(2^{13372531}+1)/3$ which is much smaller than $2^{57
885161}-1$ (about a quarter the number of digits). Generally, PRPs take as much effort to find as Mersenne primes of a similar size, but more effort is put toward Mersenne primes because of interest, convenient software, greater publicity, and the EFF prizes.